# Is there a natural restatement of what a character (in the rep theoretic sense) in terms of modules?

Tags: representation-theory

In representation theory (of finite groups over $\mathbb{C}$), most of the basics can be restated in an easier and more intuitive way using (left) $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules. However, I don't see a natural way to define a character of a rep in terms of $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules?
If $M$ is a (left) $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module, left multiplication by $g\in G$ defines a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-linear endomorphism (really an iso), and then we can take the trace of the corresponding matrix. Is there a more natural way to define trace in terms of $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules than this? Should we allow this definition to extend to the trace of any $G\ni x = a_1g_1 + \cdots +  a_ng_n$, since left-multiplication by $x$ may not be an isomorphism?

Comment: Sure - a representation of $G$ on $V$ is a left $\mathbb{C}G$-module, which is a map of algebras $\rho : \mathbb{C}G \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$. The character is $x \mapsto \operatorname{trace}(\rho(x))$. However, the data of a character table is quite group-specific, and may not translate so well to the module setting - you are also involving a special subset of elements $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}G$ in the algebra.

Comment: A minor correction: left multiplication by $g$ is typically not $ℂ[G]$-linear, but only $ℂ$-linear, unless $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Oh right, thanks!

Comment: @Joppy I think I'm missing something here. How is this different than the characterization I made in my question, aside from the fact that I said $\mathbb{C}[G]$ linear when it's really only $\mathbb{C}$-linear?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question - I was pointing out that it does indeed make sense to extend the trace to linear combinations of group elements. You might need to clarify what you mean by "natural way to define a character" - for example what are other definitions you would consider "natural" for $\mathbb{C}G$-modules?

Comment: @Joppy Ahh I see. Thanks! I guess "natural" was ill-defined, sorry about that. I guess also that this is the simplest/most "natural" way to define characters for $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules.

Comment: you may be thinking of trace purely in terms of how they are defined from matrices, but see also other interpretations here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13526/geometric-interpretation-of-trace; in particular here's an abstract algebraic perspective I like https://mathoverflow.net/a/214552/112504

Comment: @D.R. Thanks for the thread!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is maybe a partial answer to your questions:

Let $$ be a field and let $A$ be a $$-algebra.
In the following, all occurring modules and representations are required to be finite-dimensional over $$.

Every $A$-module $M$ comes with a homomorphism of $$-algebras $ρ_M \colon A \to \mathrm{End}_(M)$, given by $ρ_M(a)(m) = am$ for all $a ∈ A$, $m ∈ M$.
This allows us to define the character of $M$ as the map
$$
  χ_M
  \colon
  A \longrightarrow  \,,
  \quad
  a \longmapsto \mathrm{tr}(ρ_M(a)) \,.
$$
This generalizes the notion of a character of a group representation:

- Let $G$ be a group and let $V$ be a representation of $G$ over $$. Let $M$ be the corresponding $[G]$-module.
  For the resulting characters
  $$
    χ_V \colon G \longrightarrow  \,,
    \quad
    χ_M \colon [G] \longrightarrow  \,,
  $$
  the character $χ_V$ is the restriction of $χ_M$ to $G$.

This notion of a character of an $A$-modules satisfies many properties that we are used to from characters of group representations:

- Isomorphic modules have the same character.
- For every short exact sequence of $A$-modules $0 \to N \to M \to P \to 0$ we have $χ_M = χ_N + χ_P$.
- This entails that $χ_{M ⊕ N} = χ_M + χ_N$ for every two $A$-modules $M$ and $N$.
- We have $χ_M(1) = \dim_(M) ⋅ 1_$ for every $A$-module $M$.

Characters of representations of groups are known to be class functions.
This can be generalized to characters of $A$-modules:

- Given a group $G$, every map $f'$ from $G$ to $$ extends uniquely to a linear map $f$ from $[G]$ to $G$.
  The following conditions on $f$ and $F$ are equivalent:

  - $f'$ is a class function, i.e., $f'$ is constant on conjugacy classes.
  - $f'(g h g^{-1}) = f'(h)$ for all $g, h ∈ G$.
  - $f'(gh) = f'(hg)$ for all $g, h ∈ G$.
  - $f(ab) = f(ba)$ for all $a, b ∈ [G]$.

We therefore define a class function on $A$ to be a linear map $f$ from $A$ to $$ such that $f(ab) = f(ba)$ for all $a, b ∈ A$.
We then have the following result:

- The character $χ_M$ is a class function for every $A$-module $M$.

If $M$ is a simple $A$-module, then we say that the resulting character $χ_M$ is irreducible.
We then have the following results:

- If $\operatorname{char}() = 0$ or if $$ is algebraically closed, then the irreducible characters are linearly independent.
- If $\operatorname{char}() = 0$ and $M$ and $N$ are semisimple $A$-modules with $χ_M = χ_N$, then $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic.
  (Therefore, two semisimple $A$-modules are isomorphic if and only if they have the same character.)
- If $$ is algebraically closed and $A$ is finite-dimensional and semisimple, then the irreducible characters form a basis for the space of class functions on $A$.

Comment: This is a very well-written answer. Thank you very much